# Limit Question from Calc I

Tags: calculus, limits

Compute the following limit, or show that the limit does not exist
$$\lim_{x\to 0}x^{2}e^{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\left|x^2e^{\sin1/x}\right|\le x^2e\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}0$$